# sqlpackage.exe publish conjunction exception

Tags: cmd, msbuild, sqlpackage

I'm trying to use `sqlpackage` tool for publish thought `CMD`:

```
sqlpackage /action:Publish /SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Release\Database Services.dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:test /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=TEST05,123;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
```

and I'm getting this exception:

```
** The TargetConnectionString argument cannot be used in conjunction with any other Target database arguments.
```

I don't understand what does it means, I was able to deploy it earlier using `msbuild`:

```
msbuild "Database Services\Database Services.sqlproj" /t:deploy /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=TEST05,123;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False /p:TargetDatabase="test"
```

I've found one thread which might be relevant:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52924779/11705021

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5456/using-advanced-publish-settings-for-visual-studio-database-project/), I was able to publish using this syntax:

```
sqlpackage /action:Publish /SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Release\Database Services.dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=TEST05,123;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Initial catalog=test"
```